# Is PYPDF2 the best way to find the location where text occurs on a page?

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm wanting to write program that searches for 'my_text' on a PDF page.  I want the program to return the coordinates where my_text occurs.  I'd also like to do the difference: find all text within given coordinates of a specific PDF page.  Is PYPDF2 the best way to do this? If so, how?  If not, what is a better module?

ChatGPT looks like is using an old version of PYPDF2 and is recommending using x, y, width, height = page.searchFor(my_text)[0], but I'm getting an attribute error 'PageObject' object has no attribute 'searchFor'

Comment: Not really an answer, so posting as comment. From my experience, `PyPDF` is great, but not 100%.  You may want to look into `PDFMiner`, or other PDF text extraction tools, and compare your results

Comment: Off-topic to ask for recommendations. Please use sister-site [softwarerecs.se]. E.g. [search there using tags `python`+`pdf`](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python+pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Hi so we have migrated away from PyPDF2 to PyMuPDF which has a pretty good search for function. There has been some updates/activity around PyPDF2 recently but it has not had consistent development since 2016 or so. PyMuPDF has been more recently updated.

https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-text.html

Comment: In continuation of @TheMagicRaj - you definitely should give PyMuPDF a try. In addition to text search and extraction integrated with each other, you also have integrated OCR, vector graphic extraction ... and an unequalled performance.